# Multisite, multi user login, same server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

Is it possible to run multiple websites on the same windows server under different user logins/iis managers? Basically we have multiple web masters accessing the same login/iis manager and want to split them up, it is possible for the sites to all run at the same time from 2 iis managers?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [IIS Manager permission settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831690.aspx).  This option allows you to configure permissions and delegate permissions to different sites and applications.  This would allow you to create multiple sets of credentials and control permissions to them.

Your issue with doing this may however end up being that you consume all of the remote desktop connections, instead you may want to enable remove administration of IIS and install the manager MMC Snap-In on the client machines as well.

Comment: Where is the option to remove administration of iis? User rolls?  Also how does the mmc snap-in work , more specifically?  The webmasters would not remote in to the server they would only use a remote iis manager from their machines?

Comment: Yes the snap-in is essentially the IIS Manager just running on the local machine of the webmaster.  They would open a connection and session to the remote server to manage their applications.